# Sequelize get association through another association

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a beginner question about how to retrieve the right information with associations. I have a simple setup.

**Asset**.belongsTo(Product)

**Product**.belongsTo(Vendor)

Basically, Asset > Product > Vendor.

I can include Product easily with  *db.Asset.findAll({ include: [{ model: db.Product }] })* but I'm not sure how to include the Vendor.name through the Product model. Any help would be appreciated.

-- **Edit** --

This is what I get now with only the Product association

```
           {
                 "id": 1,
                 "name": "name",
                 ...
                 "ProductId": 10,
                 "Product": {
                     "id": 10,
                     "name": "productname",
                     "model": "12345",
                     "VendorId": 2
                 }
             },
```

and what I'm hoping to get

```
         {
             "id": 1,
             "name": "name",
             ...
             "ProductId": 10,
             "Product": {
                 "id": 10,
                 "name": "productname",
                 "model": "12345",
                 "VendorId": 2
             },
             "Vendor": {
                 "id": 2
                 "name":  "vendorname"
              }
         },
```

Comment: What did you get for now? And what do you expect?

Comment: @slideshowp2 I've edited with the information. Let me know if you requires anything else.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [querying on where association in sequelize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38918840/querying-on-where-association-in-sequelize)

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Now I know I can do include multiple levels down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```js
db.Asset.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: db.Product,
    include: [{
      model: db.Vendor
    }]
  }] 
})
```

Comment: Thank you. I know it's something simple that I missed.